# MVC4 file not found HTTP404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a problem with my MVC application. When I run this application locally it the localhost is able to find the default page and the default routing seems to work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

when I FTP the built app to the hosting site. I get "resource not found or cannot be found." Error. So I change the routing to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name:   "NewRoute", // Route name
    url:    "FolderUnderRootDirectory/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

This does not seem to resolve the problem either

**FolderUnderRootDirectory** is not a ***not a virutal directory*** it is simply a folder where the app resides. It is the same folder to which the app was published usng visual studio 2010.

I have tried my hands at changing the routes and changing the default pages to something else.

I could use someones help here.

Comment: I have a feeling you will need to set a virtual directory, or move it to the root. Try setting up your local application on IIS, not built in IISExpress, like this you can mimic the production environment and fine-tune.

Comment: I had set up a virtual directory under which I placed the app and fought with that for 2 days. It did not work there.  *It ran find on the IIS locally without any hiccups. It is only the hosting site that I failed to get it to work.  I am challenged to place it in the root directory as an application as that means the bin directory of the existing website will have to be backed up and might have to deal with down time. :(

Comment: As far as i know you can't just toss a site that has a /bin directory in a subfolder and have it work without converting the folder to a virtual directory. Try this: Create a local IIS site, point the IIS folder to /somefolder, and now toss your site in /somefolder/someotherfolder, and call it from your browser, not VS, as VS when running debug has a tendancy to hide stuff is does behind your back. I'm pretty sure it won't work.

Comment: Personally i only know of 2 ways of hosting a site on IIS. In the root directory that you declared when creating the site. And in a subfolder as long as you make it a virtual directory (of course you now have the inconvenience of having to access mysite/virtualsite/). If the root site has a /bin directory and the subfolder has a /bin directory, and IIS would load up all the DLL's in one go, that would logically wreak havoc. I suggest you make it work with a virtual directory for now, and maybe if possible look into "areas" to combine the 2 sites.

Comment: Trying as I read, both your solutions. Keeping my fingers crossed, Next up tearing out my hair whatever is left of it.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using in deployment?